# Connecting to Azure Storage Queue

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-account

I have a program where I build an envelope based on an HTTP Request. My next step is to take this envelope and add it to the Storage Queue so that I can then add the payload from the envelope to a Cosmos DB. It seems as if I am unable to connect to my Storage Account.

This is my code that actually sends the envelope to the Storage account:

```
import com.azure.storage.queue.QueueClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.queue.models.QueueStorageException;
import com.azure.storage.queue.QueueClient;


public class StorageQueueSend {
    public static String send(CfLog envelope) {
        try {
            QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClientBuilder()                              
               .connectionString("AzureWebJobsStorage")
               .queueName("hyperscalerapistorage-queue")
               .buildClient();
            queueClient.sendMessage(envelope.toString());
            return "Envelope added to storage queue\n";
        } catch(QueueStorageException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

hyperscalerapistorage-queue is the name of my queue. My connection string is stored in my local.settings.json as "AzureWebJobsStorage". And I have the proper connection string also stored in an Application Setting called "AzureWebJobsStorage" in my Function App. Here is the error message I am receiving:

```
[2023-02-23T20:15:59.682Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.create'. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Azure.Storage.Queues: No valid combination of account information found.
[2023-02-23T20:15:59.691Z] Error indexing method 'Functions.create'
[2023-02-23T20:15:59.696Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.create'. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Azure.Storage.Queues: No valid combination of account information found.
[2023-02-23T20:15:59.708Z] Function 'Functions.create' failed indexing and will be disabled.
[2023-02-23T20:16:00.022Z] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
[2023-02-23T20:16:00.077Z] The 'create' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.create'. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Azure.Storage.Queues: No valid combination of account information found.
```

Comment: You're not reading from `local.settings.json` in your code; you're passing the literal string "AzureWebJobsStorage" as your connection string. You need to read it from your settings file first.

Comment: This did not work for me. I have put my connection in a different variable name and called System.getenv("hyperScalerAPIStorageQueue") in order to receive the connection string and I still get the same error. (I also did sysout println System.getenv("hyperScalerAPIStorageQueue") to ensure that the connection string is correct)

Answer (score -1):

you have to use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("app setting variable name").
also i would recommend to use a different storage account than the web job storage account

Comment: This is precisely what I already stated in my comment, posted yesterday. Also, you gave a c# example, not Java. Note that the question should be closed (it was essentially a typo), which is why I did not post a formal answer.

Comment: This did not work for me. I have put my connection in a different variable name and called System.getenv("hyperScalerAPIStorageQueue") in order to receive the connection string and I still get the same error. (I also did sysout println System.getenv("hyperScalerAPIStorageQueue") to ensure that the connection string is correct)